# Ничего нет в последних словарях. Они выводятся, а в них ничего не написано

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, словари

```
import time

def make_album(исполнитель='', альбом='', исполнитель1='', альбом1='', исполнитель2='', альбом2=''):
    исполнитель_альбом = {исполнитель: альбом}
    исполнитель_альбом1 = {исполнитель1: альбом1}
    исполнитель_альбом2 = {исполнитель2: альбом2}
    return исполнитель_альбом
    return исполнитель_альбом1
    return исполнитель_альбом2


musician1 = make_album(исполнитель='Pink Floyd', альбом='Dark side of the moon')
print(musician1)

musician2 = make_album(исполнитель1='Егор Летов', альбом1='Зачем снятся сны?')
print(musician2)

musician3 = make_album(исполнитель2='Metallica', альбом2='Kill em all')
print(musician3)

time.sleep(5)
```

**В консоли выводится это:**

{'Pink Floyd': 'Dark side of the moon'}

{'': ''}

{'': ''}

Comment: Никакой код в функции после срабатывания `return` никогда не выполняется. Строки `return исполнитель_альбом1` и `return исполнитель_альбом2` не выполнятся никогда. Выполнится только строка `return исполнитель_альбом`, которая и возвращает словарь с пустыми строками.

Comment: @andreymal как раз return исполнитель_альбом выполнится и возвратит правильное значения, но из-за того, что остальные return не возвращают ничего - значения соотвествующим им словарям не присваивается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции используются для сокращения кода, если одну и туже часть кода нужно вызывать много раз, меняя в ней всего несколько значений. Значит не нужно описывать все возможные аргументы для функции. Также код после return не выполняется и не даёт значения словарям.

```
import os

def make_album(исполнитель, альбом):
    исполнитель_альбом = {исполнитель: альбом}
    return исполнитель_альбом


musician1 = make_album(исполнитель='Pink Floyd', альбом='Dark side of the moon')
print(musician1)

musician2 = make_album(исполнитель='Егор Летов', альбом='Зачем снятся сны?')
print(musician2)

musician3 = make_album(исполнитель='Metallica', альбом='Kill em all')
print(musician3)

os.system("pause")
```